# Como pegar somente links em um código-fonte?

Tags: java

Desde de ontem à noite que tento fazer um algoritmo pra fazer busca linha por linha e retornar somente links, mas tá complicado, ou eu que sou burro mesmo ou os métodos da classe `String` , que eu sei, não ajuda muito.

Comment: Adicione parte do codigo que você tentou e também como está o arquivo onde você está buscando essas linhas.

Comment: Você está criando uma classe java pra ler algum arquivo html procurar por <a href? Não ficou claro o que você pretente fazer, posta o código pra exemplificar seu problema

Comment: Linha por linha de quê? Código fonte de quê? Dê exemplos de entrada e saída para deixar sua dúvida mais clara.

Comment: Eu não lembro como eu fiz direito, porque apaguei... mas é assim, eu tava usando o metódo charAT() e indexOf pra percorrer a linha e encontrar http://...  só queria que mostrasse todos os http://.... de uma página web qualquer

Comment: Por que a tag "java-web" ?

Comment: Achei que estaria relacionada a pergunta

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta colocando um exemplo de texto de entrada e a saída esperada para aquele exemplo. Ainda está um pouco confuso.

Comment: Como o pessoal sinalizou, essa pergunta não está clara. Você quer pegar urls? âncoras (`<a>`)? É um arquivo html, txt ou o que? Tenta editar respondendo essas perguntas e colocando o que você já fez de código, para termos uma resposta mais precisa. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando a biblioteca Jsoup isso é bem simples.

A própria [documentação](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) traz o seguinte exemplo:

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // a with href
```

O terceiro argumento do método `parse` com o valor `http://example.com/` serve para definir uma URL base para resolver URLs relativas.

A partir desse exemplo você pode usar qualquer seletor para buscar pelos links.

Há ainda outro [exemplo mais completo](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) que retorna vários tipos de URL encontrados na página, incluindo scripts, estilos e imagens:

```
public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
        String url = args[0];
        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
        Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

        print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
        for (Element src : media) {
            if (src.tagName().equals("img"))
                print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                        src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"), src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                        trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
            else
                print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));
        }

        print("\nImports: (%d)", imports.size());
        for (Element link : imports) {
            print(" * %s <%s> (%s)", link.tagName(),link.attr("abs:href"), link.attr("rel"));
        }

        print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
        for (Element link : links) {
            print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
        }
    }

    private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: desculpa a demora, fiquei sem net e acabei esquecendo da pergunta. Eu tinha resolvido de outro jeito, mas valeu aí galera. Vou usar isso aí também. O complicado é que depois que se aprender java tem que ficar olhando a documentação pra entender. Valeu mesmo aí.

Comment: @D3ll4ry Pior do que isso. Se fosse só olhar a documentação, isso até seria boa prática. O problema é conhecer zilhoes de bibliotecas.